# How to use fetch data in Intent Handler for editing Widget iOS 14?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I'm trying to make a `widget` user can edit some data using `IntentConfiguration`

I want to use some fetch data from `CoreData` in `IntentHandler` class for editing the widget like the image below.

[image]

I tried to make some codes but They don't work...

How could I solve my codes?

---

Here are the codes:

IntentHandler.swift

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext

    var timerEntity_0:TimerEntity?
    var timerEntity_1:TimerEntity?
    var timerEntity_2:TimerEntity?

    init(context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = context

        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")

        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity_0 = result[0]
            timerEntity_1 = result[1]
            timerEntity_2 = result[2]
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
   
    func provideNameOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, searchTerm: String?, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<NSString>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let nameIdentifiers:[NSString] = [
            NSString(string: timerEntity_0?.task ?? "default"),
            NSString(string: timerEntity_1?.task ?? "default"),
            NSString(string: timerEntity_2?.task ?? "default")
            // "meeting",
            // "cooking",
            // "shoping"
        ]
        let allNameIdentifiers = INObjectCollection(items: nameIdentifiers)
        
        completion(allNameIdentifiers,nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        
        return self
    }
}
```

Widget.swift

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    
    typealias Intent = ConfigurationIntent
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), name: "")
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, name: "")
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration, name: configuration.Name ?? "")
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    var name:String
}

struct TimerIntentWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.name)
            .font(.title)
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
    }
}

@main
struct TimerIntentWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "TimerIntentWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            TimerIntentWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}
```

tWidget.intentdefinition
[image]

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could display a list in the widget using fetch data from `CoreData` like the code below:

---

IntentHandler.swift

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext

    var timerEntity_0:TimerEntity?
    var timerEntity_1:TimerEntity?
    var timerEntity_2:TimerEntity?

    func provideNameOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, searchTerm: String?, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<NSString>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")

        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity_0 = result[0]
            timerEntity_1 = result[1]
            timerEntity_2 = result[2]
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }

        let nameIdentifiers:[NSString] = [
            NSString(string: timerEntity_0?.task ?? "default"),
            NSString(string: timerEntity_1?.task ?? "default"),
            NSString(string: timerEntity_2?.task ?? "default")
            // "meeting",
            // "cooking",
            // "shoping"
        ]
        let allNameIdentifiers = INObjectCollection(items: nameIdentifiers)
        
        completion(allNameIdentifiers,nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something, Ive tried various things and my fetch does not work, at best I just get a spinning wheel for a long time. I needed up creating an array and stored in in a shared group folder with is updated when the app is open and closed that us used for the dynamic selection list.

Comment: For above thing you found any solution ? Because I am stuck there.

Comment: Kurt L. And Bhavesh, store the core data files and classes in the shared group container. pawello has a very good repo that covers most of the technical problems in widgets. See https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples